# How to resolve a generated string in an R loop

Tags: r

I am trying to populate a column in an R dataframe with a value from regression results. There are 27 unique ID's in the dataframe, each with 64 row entries.
I am looping through my 27 regression results and would like to populate each of the 64 rows (per ID) with a value from a generated string. I can do all of the above fine with:

```
for (i in 1:27) {
  coef1<-paste("Gamble_results.",i,sep="")
  coef1<-paste(coef1,"$coefficients[2]",sep="")
  print (coef1)
  Gamble_results$Lambda[Gamble_results$X1==i] <- coef1

   }
```

But the code will not resolve my coef1..I get
Error in get(coef1) : object 'Gamble_results.2$coefficients[2]' not found
When of course, this coefficient can be printed directly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval(parse())` to evaluate the object given by a string. In your case it would be:

```
Gamble_results$Lambda[Gamble_results$X1==i] <- eval(parse(text = coef1))
```

Disclaimer: I know about `fortunes::fortune(106)`, I still think `eval(parse())` has its use :)